# how to remove special character in my json format

Tags: java, jquery, json

Here  is my json object I need to remove " in front and back end of my json object

```
"{"Employee" [{"id":111589,"firstName":"govind","lastName":"Lname1","company":"ABC","No1":1,"Test":null,"Test1":"name1"},
{"id":12345,"firstName":"name2","lastName":"Lname2","company":"ABC","No1":2,"Test":null,"Test1":"name2"},  
{"id":14567,"firstName":"name3","lastName":"Lname3","company":"DEF","No1":3,"Test":null,"Test1":"name3"},
{"id":1212,"firstName":"govi","lastName":"l1","company":"Ac","No1":4,"Test":0,"Test1":"name4"},  
{"id":1212,"firstName":"govi","lastName":"l1","company":"Ac","No1":5,"Test":0,"Test1":"name4"}]}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
        String json = "\"{\"Employee\":[{\"id\":111589,\"firstName\":\"govind\",\"lastName\":\"Lname1\",\"company\":\"ABC\",\"No1\":1,\"Test\":null,\"Test1\":\"name1\"},{\"id\":12345,\"firstName\":\"name2\",\"lastName\":\"Lname2\",\"company\":\"ABC\",\"No1\":2,\"Test\":null,\"Test1\":\"name2\"},{\"id\":14567,\"firstName\":\"name3\",\"lastName\":\"Lname3\",\"company\":\"DEF\",\"No1\":3,\"Test\":null,\"Test1\":\"name3\"},{\"id\":1212,\"firstName\":\"govi\",\"lastName\":\"l1\",\"company\":\"Ac\",\"No1\":4,\"Test\":0,\"Test1\":\"name4\"},{\"id\":1212,\"firstName\":\"govi\",\"lastName\":\"l1\",\"company\":\"Ac\",\"No1\":5,\"Test\":0,\"Test1\":\"name4\"}]}\"";

    if (json.charAt(0) == '"' && json.charAt(json.length() - 1) == '"') {

        json = json.substring(1, json.length() - 1);

    }

    System.out.println("JSON is : " + json);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring()` method of `String` class to remove " from start and end like below code:

**see**

```
   String myjson="PUT YOUR JSON STRING HERE";
   myjson=  myjson.substring(1,myjson.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell your json is a string so you need to parse it to a javascript object:

`JSON.parse(jsonString)`